# Self lifetime on the Deref associated type

Tags: rust

I would like to implement `Deref` for an array of buffer structs that has been constructed from FFI.
However, it's not clear to me how to annotate the lifetime of the `Deref` associated type in terms of `Self`.
Shouldn't it be safe regardless because of the lifetime elision rules for the `deref` method?

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

const FOO : &[u8] = b"foo";
const BAR : &[u8] = b"bar";

#[repr(C)]
struct Buf<'a> {
    ptr: *const u8,
    len: usize,
    _mark: PhantomData<&'a [u8]>
}

impl<'a> From<&'a [u8]> for Buf<'a> {
    fn from(b: &[u8]) -> Self {
        Self{ ptr: b.as_ptr(), len: b.len(), _mark: PhantomData }
    }
}

struct BufArray {
    array: *const u8,
    count: usize,
}

impl BufArray {
    fn new() -> Self {
        // Assume this array is constructed from FFI, fake one for brevity:
        let v : Vec<Buf> = vec![FOO.into(), BAR.into()];
        let v = std::mem::ManuallyDrop::new(v);
        Self { array: v.as_ptr().cast(), count: v.len() }
    }
}

impl Deref for BufArray {
    type Target = [Buf<'_>]; // what to do here?? 
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        unsafe { std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.array.cast(), self.count) }
    }
}
```

If I annotate `BufArray` like so, it works, but I'm not sure this is the way to go.

```rust
struct BufArray<'a> {
    array: *const u8,
    count: usize,
    _mark: PhantomData<[Buf<'a>]>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write what you have in mind, because the way `Deref` is defined does not allow it. Having a `Deref` impl on some type `T` allows you to go from `&'a T` to `&'a T::Target`, for *any* lifetime `'a` of a borrow of a `T`, and the `T::Target` type is always independent of `'a`. (If `Deref`'s `Target` type was a *generic associated type*, then this could be done, but it isn't and can't be made so.)

***If*** a `BufArray` is always an array of `Buf`-pointers to **borrowed** data (you are not trying to make `BufArray` act as an *owning* container for the buffers that would keep them alive indefinitely), then the `struct BufArray<'a>` definition is a perfectly good solution to the problem.

If you *did* want to have an owning type, then you should not use lifetimes this way, because the lifetime is **meaningless**: `BufArray::new()` allows creating a `BufArray<'a>` with *any* lifetime `'a`, which could long outlive the `BufArray` and its `Buf`s itself.

If `BufArray` owns `Buf`s, and `Buf`s own byte slices (contrary to your example using constants), then the thing to do here is to make *none* of your types have lifetime parameters (just like the Rust-native type `Vec<Vec<u8>>`, which is structurally similar to yours, does not have any lifetime parameters).

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your second paragraph, in this case `BufArray` does own the memory (i.e. it's been allocated through FFI in `new` and would be deallocated in `drop`). I would think this is safe because we have `fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a Self::Target`. While `struct BufArray<'a>` is fine, it doesn't convey the fact that `Buf` is bound by the lifetime of `BufArray`, so I would think it's kind of useless here. As you mentioned I guess I want to express something like `type Target<'a> = [Buf<'a>] where Self: 'a` (GAT)

Comment: @3XX0 The code is *sound* as you have written it, but as you note, "it doesn't convey the fact that `Buf` is bound by the lifetime of `BufArray`". Even more important, `BufArray::new()` lets you create  a `BufArray` with any lifetime whatsoever, so the lifetime becomes meaningless, and the code is only sound because `Buf` doesn't offer any operations that rely on its lifetime. If you are trying to create a struct that owns buffers and the buffers own their bytes, then you should remove *all* the lifetime parameters — just like `Vec<Vec<u8>>` does not have any lifetime parameters.